# NSURLConnection Async intermittently returns null

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

Considering the below code, I moved my app from a synchronous to asynchronous calls to stop the UI freezing. -- Everything works fine except a few small details.

When it was synchronous calls they always returned a value (even if it took a long time (5 or 6 seconds))
However now:

1. The ASync calls are sometimes really fast other times take 8 or 9 seconds ( I have fiber internet also)
2. The text data they are fetching sometimes seemingly doesn't return or they time out as the myLabel text ends up getting set with 'NULL' - I know it's not the website I'm using the API for as it always returns a value for Sync calls and in the browser.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: Error response from logs is: Response: 
Error: (null)

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:operationQueue completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
    {
        responseGBP = data;
        NSString *json_stringGBP = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseGBP encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        self.feedGBP = [parser objectWithString:json_stringGBP error:nil];


        NSString *GBP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Info Last: %@" feedGBP ObjectForKey:@"value"]];

        [myLabel setText:GBP];


    }];
```

EDIIT:: I also see "should not be able to get here" printed in the log window alot?! it's not part of my NSLog code!

Comment: Are you sure the response you're getting is *always* ASCII-encoded?  NSString returns nil when decoding fails

Comment: Also check the NSError maybe there is something that you are not sending properly.

Comment: Side note, the label should be updated on the main thread: *[myLabel performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setText:) withObject: GBP waitUntilDone: NO];*.

Comment: NSLogging the Error with :    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]); Always returns null (must be no error) will try the performselectoronmain

Comment: Not sure about the ASCII encoding, but its never failed before using Sync calls and ASCII enc?

Comment: Maybe because you tried other *URL* 's that returned *ASCII* data.

Comment: Heya still using the same urls! tried the selector on main thread, didn't make any difference! Still seeing lots of NULLS returned and really weird performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your Queue, How and where are you intializing your `operationQueue` ?
more importantly when are you calling the asynchronous connections ?

if you're calling them from within a UIView that animates, like a tableView or a scrollView, the queue will behave this way while the table/scrollView is scrolling.

To also be able to debug more info, you need to `NSLog(@"Response: %@\r\nError: %@", response, error)`

But form my experience I highly suspect the first case is causing this, you can also try using a default queue instead of your own, something like this(Not recommended, but might helps with debugging):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
```

**EDIT 1: Adding a simple code change to make things a bit easier**

So as I suspected, you're firing calls from within animating views which causes the delays sometimes, what I would do is revert the aSync connections to Sync ones, but call them on a background thread instead.

Here's how things should look (Untested code, might contain errors or need some tweaking)

Move your call into a new method, call it something like performRequest:(URLRequest*)req;

-(void)performRequest:(URLRequest*)aRequest{

```
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *returnData;

returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:aRequest
                                   returningResponse:&response
                                               error:&err];

if(!err && nil != returnData){
   //Perform action with your data here
   //IMPORTANT: if you have to use the data to update the UI again, then you
   //Must perform that on the main thread, this code will always be called in the
   //background thread, to do that simply do a call using GCD on the main Queue, like this

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Do only your UI updates here
    });

}else{
   NSLog(@"An error has occurred: %@", err);
}
```

}

And whenever you need to perform the network request, (from within your animations, etc..)
you simply call it in a background thread, like this

```
//Place this right after you create your requestGBP request
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performRequest:) withObject:requestGBP];
```

Give it a try this way and let me know how things for for you !

Comment: It's kinda a bit messy, I'm writing an app that takes FX prices and shows them on a ticker, so - the tickers are always animating, I have a method that is firing on a timer (every 10 seconds) and this calls the asynchronous NSURLConnections. which in turn fetch data and set the strings on the tickers... One other thing to note is i'm calling the NSURLconnection from within a UIView animation block completion and then also calling

Comment: further UIView animations in the NSURLConnection completion block... but I wouldn't have thought this would cause a problem...     Workflow ---->> UIVIEW animation block makes labels slightly transparent (alpha) ----->> in completion for animation block I call --->> NSURLCOnnection Async ---->>> in NSURLConnection completion block another animation --->> labels return to opaque to show they have updated.   Didn't have any issues with Sync calls all worked perfectly with the same workflow! any thoughts?

Comment: PS operation queue is ivar and also init like this:         operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3]; initialised in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I am also getting this error: Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x919d100>
Error: (null)
 using the logging you suggested, always a different error code though

Comment: Seems we know where the issue is stemming from now, too much mess as you said ;)

I have an idea to clean up things a bit, I'll edit my answer cause i'll include code snippets, gimme a sec

Comment: Cool! I'll get back as soon as I've tried this and let you know thanks!

Comment: Hello! Initially this seems to have worked! Only have it in for one ticker and only a quick test, let me clean up the code and check for all and make sure rest of functionality is working and i'll come back to you!

Comment: Hey Mostafa! Thank you so very much for your help on this! it's now working correctly!! such a fantastic solution - now the UI is responsive during NSURLConnection data calls...

About your solution, a couple of questions:
1. Why do we have async calls, if you can just use sync on a background thread?
2. Why does Async inside an animating View cause such problems?
3. This magic: "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()" --- how does it work? what does it do!
4. Is dispatch_async different to performSelectorOnMainThread?
Thanks again!! Regards,John

Comment: @JohnWoods It's pretty simple really 1.Because async calls can run on main threads, but inside a queue, so basically it's put in an NSOperationQueue and when it's done it executes the given block, this is not the case as running in a separate thread. 2.Because async calls run inside NSOperationQueues, which will be run in the same queue as your view's Animation, causing it to block while the view is animating. 3.you might want to read a bit more about GCD, but it's basically a more abstract implementation built over threads.
4.They are almost the same yes ! :)

Comment: Fantastic, so whenever I want to run something on the main thread asynchronsously I can just call this block!? cool. Thanks a lot for the help again, upvoted and answered :)

Comment: Yes, that's how you run things on main thread, it's recommended only for UI updates, and it's like the "magic pill" for responsive apps ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check if *error* isn't *nil*, and in this case print it, it will help you understanding the problem. I'll also riassume here what said in the comments about the encoding (by CodaFi), and about updating the UI on the main thread (this isn't the cause of the problem, but it might become annoying later):

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:operationQueue completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the right string encoding:
        NSStringEncoding encoding= NSASCIIStringEncoding; // This in case the page will
                                                          // not return any encoding.
        if(response.textEncodingName)
        {
            encoding= CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef) text.encodingName));
            // A bit messy right? Don't get lost, read these functions on the 
            // documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html
        }
        responseGBP = data;
        NSString *json_stringGBP = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseGBP encoding: encoding];
        self.feedGBP = [parser objectWithString:json_stringGBP error:nil];
        NSString *GBP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Info Last: %@" feedGBP ObjectForKey:@"value"]];
        // Update the UI on main thread:
        [myLabel performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setText:) withObject: GBP waitUntilDone: NO];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Ramy, here's the response I get from logs: Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x919d100>
Error: (null)  and another example: Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x75bdfa0>
Error: (null)

Comment: What variable should text.encodingName be here?  Thanks!

Comment: A method executed on a *nil* target never gets executed and the return value is *nil*. So there's a cascade effect, and you can't know what is the "failing" (returning *nil*) method that causes the problem. Try putting a breakpoint inside the block to see where you get the *nil* string (*json_stringGBP*, *feedGBP* or *GBP* ?) and let us know.